# KStream - converting Windowed count into new String, String topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a stream of keyed numbers that are run into (Windowed) `.countByKey()` and then creating averages in a `.forEach()`.

I'd like to take the Windowed values, pair them with the start and end values and put this into a new stream. I can do this with a "traditional" Producer but Id like to keep all the work in a single app (instead of having a 2nd app to deal with the values in the new topic).

The `.forEach()` comes in as a **KTable<Windowed<String>, Long>** and I don't see an obvious operator to chain this (via `.to()` or `.through()`) to a **KStream<String, String>** topic.

Is this possible? Does the question make any sense?

Comment: The return type of `foreach()` is `void`, that's why you can't chain it in the DSL.

Comment: > I'd like to take the Windowed values, pair them with the start and end values and put this into a new stream.

Is this for something like a financial app for stock ticker data that needs to compute e.g. Open/Low/High/Close (of a window)?

Comment: This is for outlier detection. I want to take rolling averages and compare across these. The averages will be output from `.foreach` across the Windowed `.countbykey()`. I want to take the resultant values, pair them with the corresponding start and end times and output a hash (JSON). This will go with other hashes to be used for comparisons.

Comment: Instead of using `.foreach()` (which returns void), functions like `map()`, `flatMap()`, etc. would allow you to "do stuff" with each item, and then chain the results with `to()` or `through()`.  But I suppose you already know that?  `process()` would give you more flexibility, e.g. interact directly with 1+ state stores, but keep in mind the return type is `void`, too -- so you'd need to write to Kafka from within your custom `Processor`.

Answer (score 0):

Just map it to the new "key"

```
toStream()
.map((k,v) -> KeyValue.pair(k.key(), v))
.to...
```